# why am I getting No such file or directory message while running a command in linux

Tags: bash

I am testing an application by starting certain commands in sequence. During which for one of the command when I get into the directory and run it it works where as when I run directly it gives No such file or directory

**cd /opt/abc/** then running **gulp serve** will work

Where as when I run directly - **/opt/abc/gulp serve** it fails

Attached is the snapshot of the same.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BdUW.jpg)

Comment: Whats the output of `type -a gulp`?

Comment: Try `./gulp ... ` when you are in that directory.

Comment: What's the output for `which gulp`?

Comment: This is to bring an application UI up and running.

Comment: entering the command gulp serve will start the application up  12:31:45] Starting 'build'...
[12:31:45] Starting 'clean'...
[12:31:45] Finished 'clean' after 37 ms
[12:31:45] Starting 'assets'...
[12:31:45] Starting 'themes'...
[12:31:45] Starting 'fonts'...
[12:31:45] Starting 'js'...
[12:31:45] Starting 'views'...
[12:31:45] Starting 'test-data'...

Comment: The output of gulp is /usr/bin/gulp

Comment: Could be that the first `gulp` in your PATH is not `/opt/abc/gulp` and that `/opt/abc/gulp` is 32-bits while you are on a 64-bits system. Check that: `which gulp` first (to see which `gulp` is first in your PATH) and `file /opt/abc/gulp` to know more about that executable and `uname -a` to see which OS you are running. If I'm guessing right install the 32-bits libraries for you OS or use the already installed 64-bits version.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking that PWD is in your PATH, which as root it should not be (I personally don't think it should be for any user, but definitely not the super user).

So, when you type in "gulp serve" it's checking your path and finding "gulp".  If you type `which gulp` you can see where it finds it.  When you type the path to gulp, it is not finding an executable there.  So-- that's not the one you want, and if there is a file called gulp there it is not executable.